# Add one more row to the table of Angular material calendar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to append one more row to each table of an Angular calendar.

Here is the [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-gx4xav).

I know in jQuery we can use the append functionality but I'm not sure how I can do it in the case of an Angular Material calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ordinary DOM functions for this:

```
@ViewChildren(MatCalendar, {read: ElementRef}) calendars: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.calendars.forEach(calendarEl => {
    const tbody: HTMLElement = calendarEl.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody');
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  })
}
```

You will need to add content and also make adjustments if the last row of the calendar table does not have 7 columns.

Comment: Care to update the stackblitz, this code seems fine but its not doing anything in my local

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br>`after `<mat-calendar>` tag in your html file.

```
<div *ngFor="let m of months">
<mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass()" [startAt]="m" [selected]="selectedDate" 
(selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: I have rows n cells in the table. I need to append one more row. This is applicable for spacing

Comment: My bad,  I might have slight misunderstanding, Can you please tell me what is the table you are referring to ? I have your stackblitz example and i do not see any table. Are you trying to achieve appending row dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, row the date-calendar table